# How to lock items when we do check out in commerce applications

Tags: java, web-applications

I have a specific requirement. Lets say we have 3 items and a user has selected all 3 items to buy. I need to lock the 3 items (meaning the other people who want to buy the same items cannot view it) for around 10 minutes. How do I implement this?

I am developing a Java web app using Hibernate and struts.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldnt lock them at all.  Double check at checkout that they are available, and display a message if someone had bought the last one before the buyer checked out.  I suspect a fairly high % of items are placed into a cart and never checked out.  Depending on the nature of the site it could mean lost sales.

If you really do want to reserve the items, you might track a 'in cart' total for each item.  Increment the 'in cart' field by 3 when 3 are added to a cart, and then after 10 minutes (or when a sale is made) remove them.  Only show items where 'total inventory' - 'in cart' are greater than zero.